# laravel, показать языковые переменные из js

Tags: javascript, laravel, transition

Возможно ли вызвать из jsa такую конструкцию {{ trans('main.'+my_js_var) }}, что бы она показала правильную языковую переменную?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял то вам нужно нечто следующее
{{ trans('main.'+ '<?= $my_var ?>') }}

Из вопроса непонятно вам надо использовать переменную в php из js или наоборот?

Comment: Нет, blade к тому времени уже скомпилировался.